# What speed is my RAM currently running at?

Tags: memory, motherboard, memory-speed, xmp

My RAM is rated at 3600 MHz. DDR4, 2 x 8GB, slots 2 and 4. In the BIOS, I have (I think) enabled XMP Profile 2. When I check CPU-Z, I get (I think) 933 MHz:

*FIGURE 1*

[image: CPU-Z > Memory > DRAM Frequency]

When I switch to the SPD tab in CPU-Z, I get the following:

*FIGURE 2*

[image: CPU-Z > SPD > Slot #2]

Here's a picture of the relevant section of my configuration in UEFI, which I think indicates that it's running at the rated 3600 MHz:

*FIGURE 3*
[image]

**Is my memory running at 3600 MHz (~2x1798=3596) or 1866 MHz (2x933) or some other speed?**

Comment: When you boot into UEFI what does it indicate the memory is running at?

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated the Question to add a pic of the UEFI configuration. I THINK that the block saying "DDR4-3600" is the highlighted one, indicating that it's running at 3600 MHz?

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that my UEFI was showing the memory at 3600 MHz, no application in Windows reflected that. However, changing the DRAM Frequency in UEFI to 3000 MHz caused caused CPU-Z to show an 'Uncore Frequency' of 1497.0 MHz (x 2 = ~3000 MHz) and Task Manager to show a speed of 3000 MHz (up from ~2100 MHz).

In short, the UEFI lied about the actual speed, but Windows Task Manager very clearly showed the speed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The displayed numbers are not exact.
In any case, since the memory has dual channel
you need to multiply the displayed number by a factor of two.

As "933 x 2 = 1866", your memory's official rating is somewhere near to
that number, rounded to 100.

Just to note that the official rating (as described when you bought the memory),
is almost never exactly what you get.

Comment: So just to be clear, it's the "DRAM Frequency" in Figure 1, 933.0 MHz, that I need to multiply by 2, or the "XMP-3596 Frequency" in Figure 2 of 1798 MHz that I need to multiply by 2?

Comment: It's the "DRAM Frequency". I also tested on my computer, and the result came within a few dozens of the rated frequency.